# Pergunta foi marcada como duplicata, mas original não tem resposta

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas

A [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76478/26643) foi marcada como duplicata. Mas a pergunta associada não tem nenhuma resposta. Eu achei que nem era possível marcar como duplicata de pergunta sem resposta (aceita ou com votação positiva).

Comment: A ideia de marcar como duplicata nesses casos é incentivar o OP a editar e quem sabe melhorar a pergunta original, sem recorrer a fazer novas perguntas

Comment: Ohhh, a pergunta é do mesmo autor!! Não tinha reparado. Mesmo assim, não sabia que era POSSIVEL marcar como duplicada se a original não tem resposta.

Comment: @RSinohara Só é possível se for do mesmo autor, caso contrário o sistema não permite.

Answer (score 9):

Sim, deveria porque não pode ficar replicando a mesma pergunta para conseguir mais atenção. Acho até que ela deveria ser removida.

Quando a pergunta é do mesmo autor dá para fechar mesmo não tendo resposta, porque é provável que o próprio autor tenha colocado mais de uma vez porque não obteve resposta antes.